# How does GRUB load the kernel at 0x100000

Tags: x86-64, grub2

I'm writing a bootloader and kernel from scratch and my goal is to create a kernel that can both be loaded by GRUB  and my bootloader.  The issue isn't with the kernel, though.  I don't know how to load the kernel at 0x100000 which is where grub loads the kernel.  0x100000 is not small enough to fit into a 16 bit register and it is too large to reach using segmentation (using address buffer es:bx when reading the disk using BIOS interrupt).

So my question is, how does GRUB load the kernel that far into memory?

Comment: I don't know how GRUB does it but you can easily do it in unreal mode

Comment: Wouldn't I be required to write a disk driver though?

Comment: You can use BIOS interrupts in that mode, so no problems there. It's just real mode with huge segment limits.

Comment: Harold is correct that you can use [unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode) that allows you to potentially address all 4gb of memory without being in protected mode. There is an example of getting into big unreal mode on the [OSDev Wik](http://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode#Big_Unreal_Mode). You'll be able to use 32-bit registers on memory accesses. The problem is the BIOS disk read routines use Segment:offset so you'd have to load the sectors into the first 1mb and then copy them to 0x100000 and above (using something like instructions `movsb` would work

Comment: To get unreal mode to work properly to address all 4gb of memory you'll also have to ensure the A20 is enabled http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line

Comment: Yeah I got that far... And then switching from unreal to pm or lm is the same as switching from real?

Comment: Yes, being in unreal mode doesn't alter the process of jumping into protected mode or 64-bit long mode

Comment: Cool.  Question answered.  Thanks, guys.